# Find Cumulative sum React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to find the cumulative sum of an array column called csTotCommit. I get the below index error about using a number to index the array.

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'IBasis'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'IBasis'.ts(7053)
on this item: **prev[curr.csId]**

What can I do differently to index or get this cumulative sum from my array.

Here is my code:

```
  const cumSum = (data: IBasis[]) => {
    data.reduce((prev: IBasis, curr: IBasis) => {
      if (curr.csId && curr.rankId) {

      prev[curr.csId]? prev[curr.csId] += curr.csTotCommit : prev[curr.csId] = curr.csTotCommit
    }
  })
  };
```

Here is my interface:

```
export interface IBasis {
  rankId: number | null,
  csTrancheId: number | null,
  csId: number | null,
  csTotCommit: number | null,
  csBasisPerUnit: number | null,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce function first input is the cumulative result.

```
    const cumSum = (data: IBasis[]) => {
    data.reduce((total: number, curr: IBasis): number => { 
      if (curr.csId && curr.rankId) {
      
       total +=  curr.csId?? 0;   // '?? 0' will add zero when csId is null
       curr.csTotCommit = total;
     }
      return total; // you always have to return cumulative total
  }, 0) // starting with total as zero.
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, I have trouble returning this as an array. I tried number[], but having issues.

Comment: I have updated the answer will that will that help

Comment: Thanks vaira...really helped me.